# Postgres: how to specify parameters in where statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

In T-SQL I can specify parameters in where statement like this:

```
declare @start date set @start ='2021-10-10'
declare @start date set @end ='2021-10-10'

select * 
from dbo.table 
where date between @start and @end
```

How can I write the equivalent statement in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution may depend on the scope where you need to use your parameters :

If the scope is just one plpgsql function or procedure, you can simply `DECLARE` your parameters as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-declarations.html).

If the scope is one transaction or session, you can alter and query configuration parameters at run-time as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) using the `set_config` and `current_setting` functions :

```
txt = set_config('myvar.startdate','2021-10-10', false) ;
txt = set_config('myvar.enddate','2021-10-10', false) ;
select * 
from dbo.table 
where date between current_setting('myvar.startdate') and current_setting('myvar.enddate')
```

If the scope is multi sessions, you can define configuration parameters at the database level as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-alterdatabase.html) :

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET myvar.startdate = '2021-10-10' ;
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET myvar.enddate = '2021-10-10' ;
select * 
from dbo.table 
where date between current_setting('myvar.startdate') and current_setting('myvar.enddate')
```

You may need to convert the configuration parameters to the type of the date column in the query, for instance :

```
where date between CAST(current_setting('myvar.startdate') AS timestamp with time zone) and CAST(current_setting('myvar.enddate') AS timestamp with time zone)
```